# I have session state with custom in my web.config value, as I have encrypted the sqlConnectionstring but while running my web application giving error

Tags: c#, sql-server

The below Session state tag is there in my web app as I have encrypted the sqlconnectionstring and tried to run the application then it is throwing an error.

[image]

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="AzureSessionProvider" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="skDbEzNuel83QqLW0y57seO9zctiKTJ9fw0dZo7B2HZYE42oQuDZMBVpqSuVyOEpfCxNH+WSMULY0TLNE5XhX9f0fTKiy2wgHqf2L6mZZhjjHXsZjl6ifHRY1kM0jYlr"  >
        <providers>
          <add writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" name="AzureSessionProvider"  type="Azure.Utilities.SqlSessionStateStore, Azure.Utilities" />
        </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Please provide the fix on this as I checked this issue also it is telling improper connection string as it is not working with encrypted string.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow please take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), than improve your question

Answer (score 0):

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/aspnet/configure-sql-store-session-state

The sql-connection-string should have data-source..

```
data source=127.0.0.1;user id=<username>;password=<strongpassword>
```

Comment: I have data source in my sql connection string  but I have encrypted the sql connection string and then running the application so it is throwing error as below  : ---                       Error parsing <sessionState> sqlConnectionString attribute: Keyword not supported: 'vbznpmfiqe5y786p5gbqiktzofstm+qodbgutszyq4ssd+zewl4//uvu/yv1odd0d8d8sursryopuxxynibf9bifpp75otvhsm5ojaahehu'.                                                                                                   So please help on this, how to fix the issue so that i can run my application with encrypted connection string.